# How to use two different keytab in one spark sql program for read and write

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark **SQL** program in which *user1* has permission to read the data from the hive table and user2 has access to write data into the **HDFS** directory. I am submitting a spark job using *user2* keytab as *user2* has access to **HDFS** directory and also doing *kinit* with *user1* before reading hive table but, *user1* does not have access to **HDFS** directory, hence my job is failing with `AccessControlException`.

Below is the sample code,

---

```
// start spark session
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                            .appName("Spark Hive Example")
                            .master("yarn")
                            .enableHiveSupport()
                            .getOrCreate();
                            
// kinit logics for user1
---
---
                            
// read data from hive table
Dataset<Row> dataSet = spark.sql("select * from USER_DB.customer").cache(); // user1 has access

// write as CSV into HDFS
dataSet.write()
        .format("csv")
        .option("sep", ",")
        .option("quote", "\"")
        .option("charToEscapeQuoteEscaping", ",")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        .save("/app/logs/output"); // user2 has access
```

---

**Spark submit command** - spark-submit --class className --deploy-mode client  --principal user2@principal --keytab user2@Domain --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 4g --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 2 className.jar

When I submit this job, It is submitted with *user1* because of *kinit* code due to this I am able to read data as user1 has permission but not able to write as *user1* does not have permission to `/app/logs/output` **HDFS** directory

Need help on this
Thank You.

Comment: What you want to do is, either a security breach, or the proof that Roles were not defined correctly in your cluster. It's much easier technically to edit one of the Roles and add privileges.-- or even create a new Role (and optionally a new user). At some point, managers/architects have to eat their own shit.

Comment: try to check Knox Gateway url for hive.

Comment: Managing 2 different `UserGroupInformation` objects and running code against the 1st then against the 2nd -- technically that's possible with the **low-level Java API in `hadoop-auth`**. But that would require patching the entire Spark code base.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, Do I need to provide access to user1 for HDFS directory then?

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: change the security settings of your cluster so that you have a single user with sufficient privileges.

Option 2: dump the CSV files on a local Linux filesystem, with user A; then upload them to HDFS with user B. That's inefficient and breaks all lineage tracking, but that's the cost of lame Security settings.

Comment: I think option 1 will be good because dumping CSV to Local and then to HDFS will cause a performance hit.